# There are no css and js when installing openX

Tags: openx

Console shows 2 errors: can't find variable $ and Can't find variable: initPage. Page looks like no one css and js included.
After installation (captcha not seen too) situation the same. Admin panel has no css and javascripts :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OMG, it was AdBlock.  Disable for using openx